# INSERT INTO - Reference outer table in Values subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am not that good at subqueries. I am trying to essentially create columns by selecting certain values from another table, and then insert those columns into my table [Presummary 7/24 . . . AM]. The thing is in my select subqueries to generate the values I want to be inserting, I reference the workstation column of my table [Presummary 7/24 . . . AM]. I think Access SQL is saying I am not allowed to do that, but I'm not sure how to get around doing it.

Here is my query (generated by VBA function I wrote):

```
INSERT INTO [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:07:33 AM] (660201, 660202, 660203, 660206, 660207, 660208, 660209) 
VALUES (
     SELECT h.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h WHERE Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660201' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h.WORKSTATION, 
     SELECT h.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h WHERE Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660202' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h.WORKSTATION, 
     SELECT h.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h WHERE Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660203' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h.WORKSTATION, 
     SELECT h.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h WHERE Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660206' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h.WORKSTATION, 
     SELECT h.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h WHERE Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660207' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h.WORKSTATION, 
     SELECT h.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h WHERE Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660208' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h.WORKSTATION, 
     SELECT h.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h WHERE Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660209' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h.WORKSTATION
)
```

When I try running this code it says 
  "Syntax error in query expression 'SELECT h.sumOFHRS_CLA . . . workstation = h.WORKSTATION". (It is only referencing the first subquery, but I'm sure that the same error applies in all the subqueries).

The below does not work either:

```
INSERT INTO [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:07:33 AM] (660201, 660202, 660203, 660206, 660207, 660208, 660209) 
VALUES (
     SELECT h1.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h1, 
     SELECT h2.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h2, 
     SELECT h3.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h3, 
     SELECT h4.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h4, 
     SELECT h5.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h5, 
     SELECT h6.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h6, 
     SELECT h7.SumOFHRS_Claimed FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] as h7
)

WHERE Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660201' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h1.WORKSTATION
AND Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660202' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h2.WORKSTATION
AND Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660203' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h3.WORKSTATION
AND Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660206' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h4.WORKSTATION
AND Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660207' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h5.WORKSTATION
AND Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660208' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h6.WORKSTATION
AND Right(h.MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660209' AND [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = h7.WORKSTATION
```

How do I get the result I want to from my query?

Comment: is `SumOFHRS_Claimed` a valid column name? Do you really have a table named `[Presummary 7/24/2014 11:07:33 AM]` ?

Comment: Yes, both are for sure. They are both generated from my VBA from variable names, and this query listed above is also generated in VBA from those same variable names

Comment: Never figured out the true cause of the syntax errors. But regardless, for what i was trying to do, I realized I needed to use an UPDATE rather than INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured out the true cause of the syntax errors. But regardless, for what i was trying to do, I realized I needed to use an UPDATE rather than INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2...) SELECT column1, column2.. FROM tablename1 WHERE conditions`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
INSERT INTO [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:07:33 AM] (660201, 660202, 660203, 660206, 660207, 660208, 660209) 
SELECT Sum(IIF(Right([qry EngineHoursSummaryA].MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660201', [qry EngineHoursSummaryA].SumOFHRS_Claimed, 0)) As E1, 
       Sum(IIF(Right([qry EngineHoursSummaryA].MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660202', [qry EngineHoursSummaryA].SumOFHRS_Claimed, 0)) As E2, 
       Sum(IIF(Right([qry EngineHoursSummaryA].MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660203', [qry EngineHoursSummaryA].SumOFHRS_Claimed, 0)) As E3, 
       Sum(IIF(Right([qry EngineHoursSummaryA].MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660206', [qry EngineHoursSummaryA].SumOFHRS_Claimed, 0)) As E4, 
       Sum(IIF(Right([qry EngineHoursSummaryA].MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660207', [qry EngineHoursSummaryA].SumOFHRS_Claimed, 0)) As E5, 
       Sum(IIF(Right([qry EngineHoursSummaryA].MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660208', [qry EngineHoursSummaryA].SumOFHRS_Claimed, 0)) As E6, 
       Sum(IIF(Right([qry EngineHoursSummaryA].MODULE_ENGINE_SWO_SERIAL,6) = '660209', [qry EngineHoursSummaryA].SumOFHRS_Claimed, 0)) As E7
FROM [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:07:33 AM] INNER JOIN [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] ON [Presummary 7/24/2014 11:01:44 AM].workstation = [qry EngineHoursSummaryA].WORKSTATION;
```

Comment: That did not work. Says there is a syntax error on the Sum(IFF(Right . . . ) statement

Comment: Your edit was correct. The Right was missing a Open Parentheses.Does the above still don't work?

Comment: It still does not work. Gives the syntax error I posted above.

Comment: That's because you closed the parens very early try the edited (again) code. Lol